# Freeze Top Row (up/down) In Table and Allow Scroll left/right

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, html-table, row

I have some wide tables in HTML that require scrolling left/right in the browser to view.  I'd like to vertically keep the top row in place while allowing it to scroll left/right.

I have been scouring the web for something simple but I haven't found anything that allows for both of these conditions.

EDIT:
I restate my question in a possibly more clear way-
I am looking to alter existing html files with existing html tables so that the first row is fixed vertically but scrolls horizontally with the body.  I don't have control over how these html files are initially made so I must resort to adding any styling that I can through python in order to get my desired output.  In my mind there would only be one scroll bar.  Can this be done?
Anyone have an idea?

To give more information:
I have tried many options including trying to add a css class for the first row and using overflow-y as well as using multiple divs.  I would prefer to solve this in css formatting as modifying the css file is probably easier done with python than adding a bunch of divs to the already formulated html table (all of the editing is being done through python).
So far every approach at best looks a bit off and undesirably leaves a scroll bar directly under the first row.

I would like to keep the first row looking the same but just fixed vertically and allow it scroll with the rest of the rows horizontally.

Comment: why not use overflow-y? put the detialed table inside a div tag give it a height limit then the overflow-y will probably do the trick to what you want.

Comment: See above for more information and what I have tried regarding your approach.

Comment: can you post your CSS and html when you used the overflow-y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem and post my solution here in case anyone else out there is working with webpages output from excel (or just any predetermined html table in general) and wants to make the first row (or any given row) freeze vertically but scroll horizontally.  The solution relies on javascript/jquery/CSS and implementing the two div approach (I don't need a footer) discussed in the solution presented by Saechel.  I tried just about every approach and this was the only satisfactory one:

CSS file include the following:

```
#header { position: fixed;}
```

javascript file include the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){



function scroll_Table_Header()
    {
        var pos = $(this).scrollLeft();
        $("#header").animate({left: "-" + pos},1);
        //console.log("position: " + pos);
        //alert("Hi");
    }

    var firstDiv = $("<div></div>");
    firstDiv.attr("id","header");

    var secondDiv = $("<div></div>");
    secondDiv.attr("id","content");

    var colformatting = $("table colgroup").clone();

    var titlebar = $("table tr:first-child").clone();

    $("table").attr("id", "origTable");

    var newTable = $("<table id='newTable'></table>").attr("style", $("table").attr("style"));
    newTable.attr("id", "newTable");
    newTable.append(colformatting);
    newTable.append(titlebar);


    $("#origTable").before(firstDiv);

    firstDiv.append(newTable);

    secondDiv.append($("#origTable"));

    $(firstDiv).after(secondDiv);

    $(window).scroll(function(e)
    {
        scroll_Table_Header();
    });
});
```

Enjoy